# Data is not saved to the database when modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am saving a record in a global variable so that later I can modify some fields and then update that record that is in my db with .save but it does not update them

Do not update them:

```
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `workshop_managers` SET `updated_at` = '2019-01-05 22:42:56' WHERE `workshop_managers`.`id` = 11
```

My code:

I get the data:

```
            workshop = concept_payment.concept
            @workshop_manager = WorkshopManager.lock(true).find(workshop[:id])
            if (@workshop_manager.available_quantity - concept_payment.amount) >= 0
              used_quantity = @workshop_manager.used_quantity + concept_payment.amount
              available_quantity = @workshop_manager.available_quantity - concept_payment.amount

              @workshop_manager.used_quantity = used_quantity
              @workshop_manager.available_quantity = available_quantity

              @workshop_manager.save

            end
```

I tried this but it does not work either:

```
@workshop_manager.update_attributes(used_quantity: used_quantity, available_quantity: available_quantity)
```

Comment: What is `concept_payment` esp `concept_payment.amount`?

Comment: concept_payment are the workshops or services that the user chose, concept_payment.amount is the amount of those services or workshops, for example the user chose 2 workshops or 3 types of services, all these services have a limited amount

Answer (score 0):

It looks that no `@workshop_manager` attribute is changed before saving. The most probably reason is that  `concept_payment.amount` is `0`, so you don't change the quantities, so they're not saved. Ensure that `concept_payment.amount` is nonzero.

Comment: puts concept_payment.amount = print the correct amount, it's not zero